# error TS2345: Argument of type '{ x: number; y: number; z: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript, aframe

I am trying to create a-image dynamically with the values received. But somehow I am getting below error while setting the position attribute of the imgObj(code below)

`xpos, ypos` and `zpos` contains string floating values like `xpos = "-0.2", ypos="-0.1", zpos="0.2"`

```
var imgObj = document.createElement("a-image");
imgObj.setAttribute("src",'url(' + $event.src + ')');
//imgObj.setAttribute("position",{x:0,y:0,z:0})
imgObj.setAttribute('position',{x:xpos, y:ypos, z:zpos});
```

Any idea or pointers will help...thanks

Comment: if you could do this you would get `<img src=​"url" position=​"[object Object]​">​`

Comment: that is the syntax given on aframe site

Comment: it's wrong, Typescript accurately tells you that both params need to be strings

Comment: can u see aframe documentation and show me where it is wrong?

Comment: it seems to be working, are you sure this is the code throwing the errors ? fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tmnp2f6u/7/).

Comment: I think @lonewarrior556 is right... it's typescript issue not aframe issue....but I am working MEAN stack application so do not know how to bypass typescript or may be not will be able to

Comment: I have resolved it

Answer (score 0):

If you were not using aframe, that would have been the correct behaviour from TypeScript, because in DOM / HTML only world, you'd get unexpected results from giving an object as the value of `setAttribute`.

To tell TypeScript about the extra capabilities aframe adds, you can install the aframe typings:

```
npm install -D @types/aframe
```

This will add the typings that say the `setAttribute` can take an object with x,y,z numbers, when the the attribute is

Quoting from the typings https://unpkg.com/@types/aframe@0.8.0/index.d.ts :

```
export interface Coordinate {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number;
}
```

Then lower in the file:

```
setAttribute(type: 'position' | 'rotation' | 'scale', value: Coordinate): void;
```

So, looks like it should do it.

Final thought

It's worth noting that using `setAttribute` for this is not recommended by aframe, as shown in their documentation:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/position.html

> For performance and ergonomics, we recommend updating position directly via the three.js Object3D .position Vector3 versus via .setAttribute.
>
> This method is easier because we have access to all the Vector3 utilities, and faster by skipping .setAttribute overhead and not needing to create an object to set rotation:

Answer (score -3):

I guess the solution is don't use Typescript. It doesn't expect DOM methods to be overridden.

Comment: understanding your point but I am working with MEAN stack, so how could I avoid typescript?

Comment: Don't tie the A-Frame app to your stack. Keep it as a separate site and bundle that is linked or I-Framed.

Comment: I agree with your point however I might have to use it inside MEAN stack only... anyway I have found the solution and got the point that I might have to follow typescript rules along with aframe....